# Hold the command prompt until user close it from close button

Tags: c#

I going to get the command prompt from my C# application to compile some C++ files. Code is like this.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filePath = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
    }
```

But After i click the button it suddenly comes and disappear. Even its opening two command prompts. I need to Hold it and only one command prompt should appear. Can some one provide me the necessary codes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be something like so:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd",
    Arguments = @"/k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"""
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this:

```
Process.Start("cmd /k cl.exe");
```

This will launch cmd.exe, running the specified command, and keeping the window open after it's done.

Comment: That will throw a `Win32Exception` since it will interpret the full string as a file name, and fail to find the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the command from:

```
<command>
```

to:

```
cmd /k <command>
```

That will cause the command to be run, and then the window will stay open with the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own command prompt program that acts as a container and runs the required EXE files.  After running, it can use "cin" (c input) to wait for a keypress and this will stop it closing.

Comment: Thank for the support. Can you please give some sample code, So i can get it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You're not opening a command prompt as such, you're just starting a command line app that opens, have nothing to do and then closes.
If you want to open a command prompt you can call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd");`.